# Oracle : Stored procedure how to to_char expression in string variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create table dynamically in Oracle stored procedure.

I have created create table sql in the string variable.

Below is the sql snapshot and error.

Procedure is getting compiled without any issue. But when trying to execute the procedure, I am getting runtime  error. I am getting the issue because of `to_char` expression.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC12(P_TMP_Table IN VARCHAR2) AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS
    V_SQL_STMT1 varchar2(1000);
    V_TMP_Table varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    V_TMP_Table := concat('TMP', to_char(sysdate,'MMDDYYYYHH24MISSSSS'));
    V_SQL_STMT1 := 'CREATE TABLE '|| V_TMP_Table||' AS
        SELECT * from TMP_STMTSENT2 where rowid in (select min(rowid) from '|| P_TMP_Table||'
                                                                group by CUSTOMER_RELATIONSHIP_ID, to_char(''STATEMENT_PROCESSED_DATE'',''MM/DD/YYYY''))';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL_STMT1;
END;
```

**Procedure** - I need to use to_char.

```
EXEC TESTPROC12('TMP_STMTSENT2')

Error starting at line 20 in command:
EXEC TESTPROC12('TMP_STMTSENT2')
Error report:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "EDLVY.TESTPROC12", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 1
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: thanks to one all for the comments. I made it work after making the change the procedure as below.                                        to_char(STATEMENT_PROCESSED_DATE,''MM/DD/YYYY''))';

Answer (score 1):

The generated and executed statement could look like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE 10222013023309188 AS SELECT * from TMP_STMTSENT2 where rowid in (select min(rowid) from qeoiwqeoiwq group by CUSTOMER_RELATIONSHIP_ID, to_char('STATEMENT_PROCESSED_DATE','MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

The problem could be with 'STATEMENT_PROCESSED_DATE', which is not a date. Try `sysdate` instead and see if it works.

Comment: When I try to create the table as an sql it is working. But when I put in the sql snapshot which I have provided it is failing. STATEMENT_PROCESSED_DATE is the date field in the table. To get unique records i need to give to_char expression, but when I do that it is failing.

Comment: When I try to run the sql it is working. But when I put it in the snapshot it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm).  You are passing the string `'STATEMENT_PROCESSED_DATE'` to `to_char()`.  Maybe you want to pass the column or value `STATEMENT_PROCESSED_DATE` instead?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do what you are pusuing is using Oracle Temporary Tables

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1006400
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_temporary_tables_sql.htm
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php